# Google Charts send URI to ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, charts, google-visualization

I've been working with charts for quite some time and tried many different frameworks.

I tried Canvas.js,Highcharts and then i switched to Google Charts. And everything is working well except I can't get those chart to be somehow converted to canvas or just to send URI via AJAX so then on server side i can insert it to PDF.

When I console.log "data" I can see "FormData{}" in my console.log but the AJAX request is never sent to PHP.

This is my script:

```
function chartTwo() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Year', 'Revenues', 'EB', {
            type: 'number',
            role: 'annotation'
        }, 'Whole Year', {
            type: 'string',
            role: 'annotation'
        }],
        ['2013', 998, 100, 100, 150, '150'],
        ['2014', 450, 500, 500, 300, '300'],
        ['2015', 691, 250, 250, 500, '500']
    ]);

    var options = {
        width: 800,
        colors: ['##4e799f', '##a62b02', '##fd9f14'],
        series: {
            0: {
                targetAxisIndex: 0,
                type: 'bars'
            },
            1: {
                targetAxisIndex: 1,
                type: 'line',
                curveType: 'none',
                pointSize: 5,
                annotations: {
                    highContrast: false,
                    textStyle: {
                        color: '##000000',
                        fontSize: 11
                    }
                }
            },
            2: {
                targetAxisIndex: 1,
                type: 'line',
                curveType: 'none',
                pointSize: 5,
                annotations: {
                    highContrast: false,
                    textStyle: {
                        color: '##000000',
                        fontSize: 11
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            position: 'bottom'
        }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_two'));

    // Renders chart as PNG image 
    var chart_div = document.getElementById('chart_two_image');
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {

        chart_div.innerHTML = '<img src="' + chart.getImageURI() + '">';

        // create a formData object and add the image to it 
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append('pdfBody', chart.getImageURI());
        console.log(data);

        // send the formData object to the php function via ajax
        $.ajax({
            url: 'make.php?method=make',
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            dataType: "json",
            processData: false,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (results) {
                console.log('success', results);
            },
            error: function (results) {
                console.log('error', results);
            }
        });

    });

    chart.draw(data, options);

}
```

Is there any other way to convert those graphs into canvas and then send it to ajax ?

Answer (score 1):

the chart method `getImageURI()` returns a base64 string
which can be used to create a png image

to send over ajax, don't really need --> `FormData`

just use a simple object...

```
        data: {
          pdfBody: chart.getImageURI()
        },
```

let ajax process the data into the query string for the get request

set `processData` to true, or just remove the property...

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'make.php?method=make',
        data: {
          pdfBody: chart.getImageURI()
        },
        cache: false,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (results) {
            console.log('success', results);
        },
        error: function (results) {
            console.log('error', results);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I already tried with this method too and it's not working.
Now I tried to make a global var with window.myVar and the at the end of script i make this AJAX call with data:myVar and it gives me:
"TypeError: $.ajax is not a function". Any Idea ?

Comment: _$.ajax is not a function_ would indicate that jquery has not been included on the page...

Comment: jQuery has been included and loaded, but ti was Slim version so that's why it was giving me this error.

Answer (score 0):

I made a global var with window.myVar and at the end of script I make this AJAX call with data:myVar and now it's working perfectly. Thanks for all the help